# IS NOT operator in C#

Tags: c#, operators

I can't find the "is not" operator in C#.
For example I have the code below which does not work. I need to check that `err` is not of type class `ThreadAbortException`.

```
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        if (err is not ThreadAbortException)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could do this: If Not object.ReferenceEquals(err.GetType(), GetType(ThreadAbortException)) Then

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just change the catch block to:

```
catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

so you can handle ThreadAbortExceptions and all others separately.

Comment: This is a better solution to the current situation. +1

Comment: Whew, that was close. I hate seeing `!(a is B)` anywhere!

Comment: Looking at the code snippet in the question actually made me confused, it was if I'd forgot how to catch exceptions. This is the correct way indeed.

Comment: Make sure to put the more general Exception object at the bottom. You should always start with the more precise type and go down with the more general one.

Answer (score 41):

In this case, wrap and check the boolean opposite:

```
if (!(err is ThreadAbortException))
```

Comment: +1: This is the normal way, but catch blocks have a better way.

Comment: +1 This answers the question stated on the subject line, so should be the accepted answer. Lee's answer is good, though for a different question.

Answer (score 8):

More than likely what you ought to do in this circumstance is:

```
try
{
   // Do Something
}
catch (ThreadAbortException threadEx)
{
   // Do something specific
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Do something more generic
}
```

You can have multiple `catch` blocks for a `try`. Always make sure to order them such that the most specific is on top, and the most generic (`catch (Exception ex)`) is last because the lookup order is from top to bottom, so if you put the `catch (Exception ex)` first, it will always be the only one to run.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick note: as of C# 9, you should be able to use 'is not'.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

This doesn't change the best answer. In your case, I still support:

```
catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

I recently had a case where I needed to ensure an inner exception was *not* something, though, so I ended up having to use:

```
try
{
   // Some code
}
catch (SomeException ex)
   when (ex.InnerException is not SomeOtherException)
{
   // Something I know how to handle
}
```

So, again, I don't think this changes the answer to the original question, but for future reference this is now possible.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
if(err.GetType() != typeof(ThreadAbortException))
{

}
```

But I **strongly recommend** using a separate catch statement, as suggested by Lee.

```
catch(ThreadAbortException ex)
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
catch (Exception err){
    if (!(err is ThreadAbortException)) {
    //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: One reason you might want to `catch` separate exception types is that you can use a different `finally` block on each type of exception. Perhaps some exceptions are not recoverable (you clean up your resources in the finally block if these exceptions occur) while others are recoverable (you leave resources intact, and allow the caller to sort it out).

Answer (score 1):

Lee has the best answer.

Just to add, you should always catch from the most specific down to the most general. In your case the `ThreadAbortException` is the most specific so deal with that first.